# How to check if there is any file field in rails request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, request, actioncontroller

I am making a logging system which keeps track of all the request the web server is getting. How do I check if any of the requests contain any **file** i.e. any file upload action?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe check what is your request mime type.

```
request.content_mime_type.symbol
=> :multipart_form
```

If that returns `:multipart_form` you can go through the `params` values and search for kind of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`.

Comment: Your way solves the purpose, but going through each params i.e. nested params too, will be so much of an overhead and not feasible in case of high level of nesting in the params.